# Drupal AJAX Replace

Tags: ajax, drupal, replace

I'm creating a custom user settings page. I have one field: zip_code that get's it's initial value from a custom user field. I have a custom function that pulls external data using the value of the zip_code.

I currently have the default value of the field set to the custom user field (if it's available). This is working as designed; however, I want to give the user the ability to change their zip code via an Ajax callback. This would replace the already populated radio buttons with new ones. I can't seem to wrap my head around this. Here's my code:

```
 function settings_shopping_form($form, &$form_state) {
  include_once "external.inc";
  // Get user fields
  global $user;
  $user_fields = user_load($user->uid);
  $zipcode = $user_fields->zip_code['und']['0']['value'];
  if(isset($zipcode)) {
   $form['zip_code'] = array(
   '#title' => t('Zip Code'),
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#required' => TRUE,
   '#default_value' => $zipcode,
   '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'settings_form_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'textfields',
   ),
);
 $storename = getmystorename($zipcode);
 if(count($storename) > 0) {
  $form['textfields'] = array( 
   '#prefix' => '<div id="textfields">',
   '#suffix' => '</div>',
   '#type' => 'fieldset' );
  $form['textfields']['stores'] = array(
   '#type' => 'radios',
   '#title' => t('Choose your store:'),
   '#options' => $storename,
   '#default_value' => $storename[1], );
  } else {
    $form['textfields']['incorrect'] = array(
   '#title' => t('Sorry, there are no stores available near you. Check back later'),
   '#type' => 'fieldset', );
}
}
```

My callback function is very simple:

```
 function settings_form_callback($form, $form_state) {
   return $form['textfields'];
 }
```

To reiterate: I want to add the ability to replace the populated radio buttons with new buttons generated by the getmystorename function when the zip_code field is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking an example from the examples module (love it!):

```
$defaults = !empty($form_state['values']['zip_code']) ? $form_state['values']['zip_code'] : $zipcode;
$storename = getmystorename($defaults);
```

I put this before the start of my form so that the values load before the form builder.